# What were the make and model of the engine that failed in flight Southwest 1380?

Tags: jet-engine, engine, engine-failure

Regarding the [tragedy of Southwest 1380](https://www.cnn.com/2018/04/17/us/philadelphia-southwest-flight-emergency-landing/index.html) flight on 2018-04-17 involving an engine failure, what company manufactured that engine, and what engine model/type was it?

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote. I do not understand how a Question deserves 2 down-votes with an Answer that deservers 2 up-votes.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some details about your research so far.  I suspect that that is the reason for the down-vote.  (Yes I understand that you answered your own question but SE typically likes for you to show your previous research)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](http://www.news.com.au/travel/travel-updates/incidents/southwest-airlines-flight-engine-explodes-as-plane-from-new-york-to-dallas-makes-emergency-landing/news-story/6168a8db91d307f2364170fb12005281) published on news.com.au:

- Engine model is [CFM56-7B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM_International_CFM56#CFM56-7_series), debuted in 1997.
- Manufacturer is [CFM International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM_International), jointly owned by [General Electric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric) of the United States and [Safran Aircraft Engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safran_Aircraft_Engines), a division of [Safran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safran) of France.

More specifically, [AirFleets.net reports](http://www.airfleets.net/ficheapp/plane-b737ng-27880.htm):

- Engine model: CFM56-7B24
- Plane: [Boeing 737 Next Gen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_Next_Generation), variant group [737-700](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737_Next_Generation#737-700)

Answer (score 2):

More info on the flight
https://www.ntsb.gov/news/press-releases/Pages/NR20180503.aspx

NTSB Issues Investigative Update on Engine Failure
5/3/2018
WASHINGTON (May 3, 2018) — The National Transportation Safety Board issued an investigative update Thursday for its ongoing investigation of the fatal, April 17, engine failure on Southwest Airlines flight 1380.

The Boeing 737, powered by CFM International engines, experienced a failure of the left CFM-56-B engine after departing New York’s LaGuardia Airport. The engine experienced a failure of a fan blade, which resulted in the loss of the engine inlet and cowling. Fragments from the cowling and engine inlet struck the fuselage, causing a rapid depressurization. The crew conducted an emergency descent and diverted to Philadelphia International Airport. There were 144 passengers and five crewmembers onboard.  One passenger suffered fatal injuries and eight passengers suffered minor injuries. The airplane was substantially damaged.

https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/PublishingImages/DCA18MA142-update-fig1.jpg

(In this NTSB photo-illustration, damaged components of the left engine are identified as viewed from the inboard side of the CFM-56-B engine. During climb out following departure from New York’s LaGuardia Airport, the engine experienced a failure of a fan blade which resulted in the loss of the inlet and cowling. Almost the entire inner and outer barrels of the inlet cowl were missing as were the forward and aft inlet bulkheads. NTSB Photo-illustration)

According to the investigative update, the aircraft’s maintenance records indicate, the fan blades were last overhauled 10,712 engine cycles before the accident. At the time of the last blade overhaul (November 2012), blades were fluorescent penetrant and visually inspected.

The investigative update includes a summary of the interviews conducted by the NTSB with the captain and co-captain, the three flight attendants, and a SWA employee in the cabin.

The cockpit voice recorder group has completed a draft transcript of the incident. The CVR transcript will be released when the public docket is opened.

The information in the update is preliminary and subject to change as the NTSB’s investigation progresses. Analysis of the accident facts, along with conclusions and a determination of probable cause, will come at a later date when the final report on the investigation is completed. As such, no conclusions about how the incident happened should be drawn from the information contained within the preliminary report.

The incident marks the first fatality involving a U.S. registered commercial passenger air carrier since the 2009 Colgan Air flight 3407 crash near Buffalo, New York.

The full investigative update is available online at https://goo.gl/bJCGdo